# Project/Information Management Software

Tags: web-apps, php, database, project-management, inventory

We are a cell tower services start up. I'm looking for web-based software that our workers on the field can login to and record cell site visits, crew inventories, detailed information about sites including large photo libraries. There needs to be recognized relationships between data so the page for a company can show all the towers they own, project page shows related sites, etc.

We also need this data to be searchable so we can do things like pull up a site based on its FCC ID. We also need to put in companies that own the sites and be able to upload documents for them such as our SLA's.

Its not required but it would be nice if we can share site info pages with our clients so they can see all the photo libraries, visits to that site, etc.

Also please nothing cloud-hosted

Comment: "web based" but "not cloud-hosted". Does that mean you are going to host it yourself? In that case: what OS and webstack? Please [update your question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/6875/edit).

Answer (score 0):

I work for Twproject, a web based project management system (http://twproject.com) that you can install on your servers.

You can structure your projects having a root for each customer and that a sub-task for every site. Then you can define the sub-sub-task and so on in order to define your project phases and so on.

Consider that yon can attach (drag and drop) several document to each level.

Searchable documents will be indexed full-text; more refined search pages are eventually available.

Every project could be used as "template" for creating new similar ones.

Security is fine grained, and you can give access to project data (you can define it) to your customers.

Additionally it manages issues (can be used as checklist for some tasks), shared agenda, discussions, time tracking, and much more.

Twproject is built on Java and installs everywhere in minutes. It can use your database (MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle, PostreSQL, DB2 etc).

It is easy to customize it adding custom field, custom reports or custom form.

Source codes are available for free under NDA for every customer.